# TypeError: _rxjs.Observable.fromPromise is not a function

Tags: react-native, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I use `rxjs` in `React Native`. I call `Observable.fromPromise(storage.load({key: key})).map(() => value);` shows the error.

My rxjs version:

```
"rxjs": "^6.5.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
```

I have three steps.

Step1:

```
rxInit().flatMap(() => {

  console.log('I can not see the console log');

  return rxInit()

}).subscribe(() => {

  console.log('I can not see the console log');
  // some code...

})
```

Step2 rxInit():

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

  rxInit() {
    console.log('I can see the console log')

    return StorageService.shared.get('deviceuuid').flatMap((deviceuuid) => {

      console.log('I can't not see the console log')

      if (deviceuuid == null) {
        return StorageService.shared.set('deviceuuid', this.deviceuuid);
      } else {
        return Observable.of(this.deviceuuid);
      }

    }).do((deviceuuid) => {
        // some code...
    })
  }
```

Step3 about the get():

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import Storage from 'react-native-storage';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

let storage = new Storage({
  size: 1000,
  storageBackend: AsyncStorage,
  defaultExpires: null,
})  

export default class StorageService {
  set(key, value) {
    console.log('StorageService set');
    return Observable.fromPromise(storage.save({ key: key, data: value })).map(() => value);
  }

  get(key) {
    console.log('It is a ', storage.load({key: key}));  // It is a Promise
    return Observable.fromPromise(storage.load({key: key})).map(() => value);
  }

  remove(key) {
    return Observable.fromPromise(storage.remove({key: key})).catch(() => Observable.of(null))
  }
}

StorageService.shared = new StorageService();
```

I looking for some answer, somebody says it is because rxjs is above 6.0, so I try to use

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

return from(storage.load({key: key})).map(() => value);
```

It sill shows

```
TypeError: _rxjs.from.fromPromise is not a function
```

or

```
_rxjs.from().map is not a function.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you use 6 pls use the pipe() syntax. from(promise).pipe(map(.....))

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to use `pipe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that there are already some hints on the comments, but I will provide an answer to give more context to the answer.

For RxJS 6, the practice when it comes to working with RxJS operators (such as map and switchMap) would be to use the `pipe` utility, rather than dot-chaining the operators. You may read more about the changes over [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

Building onto your example, for instance, if you want to use both `map` and `filter` operators, rather than doing something like

```
from(storage.load({key: key})).map(() => value).filter(value => value)
```

RxJS 6 will require you to do this instead:

```
from(storage.load({key: key}))
  .pipe(
    map(() => value),
    filter(value => value),
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // do the rest here
  })
```